# android - change achartengine graph background color

Tags: android, colors, background, achartengine

Is there a way to change the background color of the graph intent when using achartengine?
Currently, it displays all the graphs with a black background. 
I looked into GraphicalActivity.java but couldnt find a solution.
Anyone?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in `GraphicalView.java` 's `onDraw()` method add this line

```
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

it will work

Comment: thanks. It worked. One more doubt - Im using a pie chart, and it only displays the chart, but not the values. Is there a way to display the values on the screen?

Comment: ya you can, but for that you have to brush up your mind, try buddy

Comment: it would be great if you could tell me :)

Comment: actually lil busy, i think you should try it by your own its really a good experience for you

Comment: i would prefer you to ask another question on SO, if anyone knows surely they will help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3485/discussion-between-umang-and-hotveryspicy)

Comment: mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true); is the key point here. I applied setBackgroundColor() before, but it had no effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you can add this and enjoy it!

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 2):

The response is correct, but you don't have to do that in the GraphicalView.java.
You should do that in your own class building the renderer for the chart.